# How retrieve element from collection by name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

First, I create collection from array:

```
 $bank_center = collect(array("amount" => null, "mfo" => null, "name" => null));
```

Then I try to get value by key:

```
dd($bank_center->name);
```

Dump is:

```
Collection {#562 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "amount" => null
    "mfo" => null
    "name" => null
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, the following would just work:

```
$bank_center['name'];
```

I am not sure why you want to wrap it as an object, but if you still wish to do it, I'd recommend you take a look at [Fluent](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.html).

```
$bank_center = new \Illuminate\Support\Fluent(array("amount" => 'test', "mfo" => 'test2', "name" => 'test3'));


dd($bank_center->name); // test3
```

Comment: I need to get data directly like ` $bank_center->name`

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use square brackets to access item from such collection:

```php
$bank_center['name']
```

Comment: How to convert to use like $bank_center->name?

Comment: @OPV Either use [Fluent](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.html) support class or initialize your collection with objects instead of array.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve element by name from collection you can use get method, it returns the item at a given key. If the key does not exist, null is returned:

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'bruno', 'framework' => 'laravel']);

$value = $collection->get('name');

// bruno
```